# Did a wrong merge: master to a side branch

Tags: git, git-merge

consider my `master` to an old version of the code that's not even important to me anymore as long as I have a branch called `side_branch`.

`side_branch` is up to date and has tons of differences compare to `master`

I did this:

```
git checkout side_branch
git commit -m "final version"
git push origin side_branch

git checkout master
git merge "side_branch"
```

got some conflict error and with some changes as following, the merge was successful:

```
git commit "ready to merge"
git merge "side_branch"
git push origin master
```

I think you got what is happing... as I realized I did a vice versa merge.

The problem is I don't have access (git log) to the most commits on the side_branch, as you may know now, I don't see the `final version` commit nor on the remote.

I read some similar issue on StackOverflow, so I did this:

```
git checkout "side_branch"
git merge "master"
```

Hoping to get other commits in the log, but It didn't help; so I thought before making the situation worse, Ask you, guys, to help a noobie.

what should do to get access to `final version` commit, and have this commit on my master branch?

Thank for your time.

Comment: Read this to get back to the right point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Comment: Use the reflog command as described in the answer